# The dual space of $V = \big \{ v : \sum_n n^2 |v_n|^2 < \infty \big \}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

Let
$$
V = \big \{ v = (v_n)_{n \ge 1} : \sum_n n^2 |v_n|^2 < \infty \big \}
$$
be equipped with an inner product $\langle u, v \rangle_V := \sum_n n^2 u_n v_n$. Then $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V)$ is a Hilbert space. Consider the vector space
$$
U = \big \{ f = (f_n)_{n \ge 1} : \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} |f_n|^2 < \infty \big \}
$$
with the dual pairing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{U, V}$ given by
$$
f (v) :=\langle f, v \rangle_{U, V} := \sum_n f_n v_n.
$$

I would like to verify that

> **Theorem** $U=V^*$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

Let $f \in U$ and $v \in V$. Let $|\cdot|$ be the induced norm of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V$. By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality,
$$
f(v) = \sum_n (f_n/n) (v_n/n) \le \sqrt{\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} |f_n|^2} |v|.
$$

Because $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} |f_n|^2 < \infty$, we get $U \subset V^*$. Let's prove the reverse, i.e., $V^* \subset U$. Let $i:V \to V^*$ be the canonical isometric isomorphism. Fix $u \in V$. Then
$$
\langle i (u), v \rangle_{V^*, V} = \langle u, v \rangle_V = \sum_n (n^2u_n) v_n 
\quad \forall v \in V.
$$

Notice that $u \in V$ implies $(n^2 u_n)_{n \ge 1} \in U$. It follows that $i(u) \in U$ and thus $V^* \subset U$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: If $V$ is really a Hilbert Space, then $V^* = V$. Thus $V^* \neq U$

Comment: @Maksim I took this statement from [page 137](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VfUw.png) of Brezis' [Functional Analysis](https://www.math.utoronto.ca/almut/Brezis.pdf). Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @Maksim Nothing prevents $V^*$ from being "equal" to $V$ and $U$ at the same time, precisely because it's not a true equality but only an isomorphism. The "real dual" of $V$ is still a space of fucntions from $V$ to the field of scalars, which cannot be equal to $V$ for obvious reasons. $U$ is also not truly equal to it either. But we write $V^* = V$ because we have a way to identify one to the other with Riesz's representation theorem, and we can write $V^* = U$ because we found an isomorphism between the two.

Comment: @ Bruno: Consider the constant sequence $(1,1,...)$. This sequence is an element of $U$. But not in $V$.

Comment: @Analyst Thanks for the link. In your post you wrote $V$ *is a Hilbert space*. However the paper states that $V$ is a dense subset of the Hilbert space $\ell^2$. Hence it is not a Hilbert Space ..

Comment: @Maksim Notice that the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V$ of $V$ is *not* the canonical one of $\ell^2$.

Comment: @Maksim The inner products on $U$ and $V$ are different anyway. We're not saying that $V^*$, $V$ and $U$ are equal but that they are isomorphic as Hilbert spaces. And yes, $V$ would not be complete under the $\ell^2$ norm but that is not the chosen norm here.